# google sheets QUERY IMPORTRANGE where column = A1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a below query in my test google sheet that is importing all data that matches A1

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheed_ID","Master!A2:AG558"), "SELECT Col14 WHERE Col12 contains '"&$A$1&"'")
```

the problem is that the QUERY imports all cells that contain 'A1' as well as the top title cell from the col14.

How to avoid importing that title sheet_ID!N1/col14 cell?
The N1 cell does not contain A1. It's just a header title cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're forgetting the header option at the end of the query formula: =Query(Range,Query Operation, [Header])

It is optional, so in your case if you want it to exclude the starting row, it will be:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheed_ID","Master!A2:AG558"), "SELECT Col14 WHERE Col12 contains '"&$A$1&"'",1)
```

Comment: thanks Warren, do you know how to display blank cell if the condition hasn't been matched instead of #N/A, thanks again that has worked, it also works when adding ,0

Comment: @greenszpila wrap it into IFERROR()